# How to retrieve tables which exists in a pdf using AWS Textract in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-textract

I found article below to do in python.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-export-table-csv.html

also I used article below to extract text.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/detecting-document-text.html

but above article helped to get only text, I also used function "block.getBlockType()"
of Block but none of block returned its type as "CELL" even tables are there in image/pdf.

Help me found java library similar to "boto3" to extract all tables.

Answer (score 5):

What I did, I created models of each dataset in the json response and can use this models to build a table view in jsf.

```
public static List<TableModel> getTablesFromTextract(TextractModel textractModel) {
    List<TableModel> tables = null;

    try {

        if (textractModel != null) {
            tables = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BlockModel> tableBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String, BlockModel> blockMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (BlockModel block : textractModel.getBlocks()) {

                if (block.getBlockType().equals("TABLE")) {
                    tableBlocks.add(block);

                }
                blockMap.put(block.getId(), block);
            }

            for (BlockModel blockModel : tableBlocks) {

                Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> rowMap = new HashMap<>();

                for (RelationshipModel relationship : blockModel.getRelationships()) {

                    if (relationship.getType().equals("CHILD")) {

                        for (String id : relationship.getIds()) {

                            BlockModel cell = blockMap.get(id);

                            if (cell.getBlockType().equals("CELL")) {

                                long rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
                                long columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                                if (!rowMap.containsKey(rowIndex)) {
                                    rowMap.put(rowIndex, new HashMap<>());
                                }

                                Map<Long, String> columnMap = rowMap.get(rowIndex);
                                columnMap.put(columnIndex, getCellText(cell, blockMap));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                tables.add(new TableModel(blockModel, rowMap));
            }
            System.out.println("row Map " + tables.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Could not get table from textract model", e);
    }
    return tables;
}

private static String getCellText(BlockModel cell, Map<String, BlockModel> blockMap) {
    String text = "";

    try {

        if (cell != null
                && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(cell.getRelationships())) {

            for (RelationshipModel relationship : cell.getRelationships()) {

                if (relationship.getType().equals("CHILD")) {

                    for (String id : relationship.getIds()) {

                        BlockModel word = blockMap.get(id);

                        if (word.getBlockType().equals("WORD")) {
                            text += word.getText() + " ";
                        } else if (word.getBlockType().equals("SELECTION_ELEMENT")) {

                            if (word.getSelectionStatus().equals("SELECTED")) {
                                text += "X ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Could not get cell text of table", e);
    }
    return text;
}
```

TableModel to create the view from:

```
public class TableModel {

private BlockModel table;
private Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> rowMap;

public TableModel(BlockModel table, Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> rowMap) {
    this.table = table;
    this.rowMap = rowMap;
}

public BlockModel getTable() {
    return table;
}

public void setTable(BlockModel table) {
    this.table = table;
}

public Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> getRowMap() {
    return rowMap;
}

public void setRowMap(Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> rowMap) {
    this.rowMap = rowMap;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return table.getId() + " - " + rowMap.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rikus, I see you are knowledgeable on this topic. Could you please help with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499160/aws-textract-key-value-pair-java-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar:

```java
public class AnalyzeDocument {

    public DocumentModel startProcess(byte[] content) {

        Region region = Region.EU_WEST_2;
        TextractClient textractClient = TextractClient.builder().region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create()).build();

        return analyzeDoc(textractClient, content);
    }

    public DocumentModel analyzeDoc(TextractClient textractClient, byte[] content) {

        try {
            SdkBytes sourceBytes = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(content);
            Util util = new Util();
            Document myDoc = Document.builder().bytes(sourceBytes).build();

            List<FeatureType> featureTypes = new ArrayList<FeatureType>();
            featureTypes.add(FeatureType.FORMS);
            featureTypes.add(FeatureType.TABLES);

            AnalyzeDocumentRequest analyzeDocumentRequest = AnalyzeDocumentRequest.builder().featureTypes(featureTypes)
                    .document(myDoc).build();

            AnalyzeDocumentResponse analyzeDocument = textractClient.analyzeDocument(analyzeDocumentRequest);
            List<Block> docInfo = analyzeDocument.blocks();
//          util.displayBlockInfo(docInfo);
            PageModel pageModel = util.getTableResults(docInfo);
            DocumentModel documentModel = new DocumentModel();
            documentModel.getPages().add(pageModel);

            Iterator<Block> blockIterator = docInfo.iterator();

            while (blockIterator.hasNext()) {
                Block block = blockIterator.next();
                log.debug("The block type is " + block.blockType().toString());
            }
            return documentModel;
        } catch (TextractException e) {

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and this is the util file:

```java
    public PageModel getTableResults(List<Block> blocks) {
        List<Block> tableBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Block> blockMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Block block : blocks) {
            blockMap.put(block.id(), block);
            if (block.blockType().equals(BlockType.TABLE)) {
                tableBlocks.add(block);
                log.debug("added table: " + block.text());
            }
        }
        PageModel page = new PageModel();

        if (tableBlocks.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Block table : tableBlocks) {
            page.getTables().add(generateTable(table, blockMap, i++));
        }
        return page;
    }

    private TableModel generateTable(Block table, Map<String, Block> blockMap, int index) {
        TableModel model = new TableModel();
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> rows = getRowsColumnsMap(table, blockMap);
        model.setTableId("Table_" + index);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> entry : rows.entrySet()) {
            RowModel rowModel = new RowModel();
            Map<Integer, String> value = entry.getValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
                rowModel.getCells().add(value.get(i));
            }
            model.getRows().add(rowModel);
        }

        return model;
    }

    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> getRowsColumnsMap(Block block, Map<String, Block> blockMap) {

        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> rows = new HashMap<>();

        for (Relationship relationship : block.relationships()) {
            if (relationship.type().equals(RelationshipType.CHILD)) {
                for (String childId : relationship.ids()) {
                    Block cell = blockMap.get(childId);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        int rowIndex = cell.rowIndex();
                        int colIndex = cell.columnIndex();
                        if (rows.get(rowIndex) == null) {
                            Map<Integer, String> row = new HashMap<>();
                            rows.put(rowIndex, row);
                        }
                        rows.get(rowIndex).put(colIndex, getText(cell, blockMap));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }

    public String getText(Block block, Map<String, Block> blockMap) {
        String text = "";
        if (block.relationships() != null && block.relationships().size() > 0) {
            for (Relationship relationship : block.relationships()) {
                if (relationship.type().equals(RelationshipType.CHILD)) {
                    for (String childId : relationship.ids()) {
                        Block wordBlock = blockMap.get(childId);
                        if (wordBlock != null && wordBlock.blockType() != null) {
                            if (wordBlock.blockType().equals(BlockType.WORD))) {
                                text += wordBlock.text() + " ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
```